# Update Access Database from PHP script?

Tags: php, ms-access, sql-update

I'm relatively new to PHP and databases. Currently I'm working with an existing Access database and am able to read and display the data just fine. However, I'm wanting to update a user record through an email verification link. I have the server send an email with a link of www.domain.com/verify.php?userID=#

I am able to read this GET variable just fine, but I'm completely lost as to how I update the record. Everything I search for is for updating MySQL databases whereas I'm using odbc.

Does anyone know how I could set this up?

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
odbc_exec($conn, "UPDATE table SET field=value"); // $conn is your connection identifier
```

Comment: My exact script is:

`<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
 header("location:ae_binder.php");
}
else {
 $userID = $_GET['userID'];
 
 if ($userID) {
  $connect = odbc_connect("Potter","","");
  $sql = "UPDATE aeUsers SET userVerify=1 WHERE userID=$userID";
  odbc_exec($connect, $sql);
 }
}
?>`

Yet, nothing gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a ODBC database client library in PHP to connect to a ODBC datasource. For example you can use [*PDO*](http://www.php.net/book.pdo.php) with the driver [ODBC and DB2 Functions (PDO_ODBC)](http://php.net/ref.pdo-odbc.php).